# Iterate over a proxy list selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am making a twitter **scraper** that **scrapes** the recovery info of twitter accounts
The thing is that i need to change proxys every 4 iterations
what i've came up with:

```
     from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import smtplib
import time
import sys
import os

#puts all the links into a username
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    users = [line.strip() for line in f]
#where results are stored
result = open(r"results.txt","w")
#stores the proxys
with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as f:
    proxies = [line.strip() for line in f]
counter = 0
for user in users:
        
    #adding proxy
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxies[counter])      #iniatialization of the driver
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    counter=counter+1
    #stage 1 username was entered and submitted
    url = 'https://twitter.com/account/begin_password_reset'
    browser.get(url)
    textbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form/input[2]')
    textbox.send_keys(user)
    submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form/input[3]')
    submit_button.click()
    validator= browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/form/input[2]')
    validator2=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/a')
    if not validator or not validator2:
        
        name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]").text
        email= browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/form/ul/li/label/strong").text
        result.write(user+ ":"+ name+":"+email)
```

the problem i am facing is that the proxies are not iterating and some proxies are dead so its stopping the whole program.

Comment: You don't iterate over the proxies because you call the first element of the `proxies` list in each iteration with `proxies[0]`.

Comment: @trotta i fixed it still facing a problem when the proxy is dead

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you could implement an approach choosing a different random proxy from your list every four iterations and a `try` and `except` block to deal with dead proxies like this:

```
import random

for i,user in enumerate(users):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if i % 4 == 0:
        proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    try:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxy)
        # continue with your scraping
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

You can easily improve this snippet, for example by catching the specific error when you run into a dead proxy and delete it from your list (with `.pop()`) or adding a `while` loop to repeat the iteration after you ran into an error.

Comment: i tried this but it kept telling me the connection was reset even with fresh proxies